# How to store persistent settings over multiple processes on windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

My program processes at startup command line arguments, reads some settings from a settings file and overwrites standard values I have in a settings class. This settings instance is set up once and is only read afterwards. I can import settings anywhere in the program and use them. For example the path to a directory is provided by the user at startup and used later on in the program.
The problem is that I'd like to use multiprocessing and that I have to use Windows. And on Windows I have to use the [spawn method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) to create a new process, which start with a fresh python interpreter process and removes all changes that had been done to the settings. (Example Code below)

I'd like to know if there is a smarter way to store the settings.

```
# settings.py
class Settings:
    path = None


settings = Settings()


# main.py
import multiprocessing
from settings import settings


def print_path():
    print(f"Path: {settings.path}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    settings.path = "test.csv"  # user input

    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.apply(func=print_path)  # prints "Path: None" but I'd like to see "Path: test.csv"
```

Comment: Do these settings need to persist across re-starts of the main process, or are you just trying to pass setup data to the child processes in the pool?

Comment: I'm just trying to pass setup data to the child process in the pool. I can pass them as arguments and overwrite them at the beginning in the child process, but I think this is rather ugly. And I thought there is probably a more elegant solution to "store" the setup data to begin with.

Comment: Why would the child processes be overwriting the settings if all of the initialization of the settings has been done by the main process and from that point on you indicated the settings are read only (or did I miss something)? You just need to have the setting initialization code *not* done as global code like you are showing now. You want to ensure that any settings initialization code is executed by the  main process only. So that `settings = Settings()` statement at global scope becomes very problematic.

Comment: @R.Ghazaleh "I thought there is probably a more elegant solution": Nope. Booboo is correct here. Passing settings via initialization func / args to a process is required unless you write to a file, then tell children to read from file (not that elegant...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, you want to put all of the code related to initializing the settings in a block of code that will only get executed by the main process. The easiest way to do that is to create a function called `init_settings` and place the code there and that function will be called by code within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block or by a function called within such a block. It is okay to leave at global scope class definitions (their execution overhead is minimal), especially if they are required by the subprocesses. Then you can initialize a global variable with the settings for each pool process, so that it does not have to be passed for each submitted task but rather just once for each process in the pool.

I am a bit confused, however. You have `from settings import settings` and then later you clobber `settings` with `settings = Settings()`.

Here is the general idea:

```py
# Assumption that this is used by all tasks and must be initialized
class Settings:
    ...

def init_settings()
    """
    Function responsible for creating the settings instance.
    """
    # only this function needs to do this import:
    from settings import settings
    ...
    settings = Settings()
    # Initialize this
    settings.path = "test.csv"
    ... # etc.
    return settings

def init_pool(the_settings):
    """ Initialize global variable for each process in the pool """
    global settings
    settings = the_settings

def print_path():
    print(f"Path: {settings.path}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing

    settings = init_settings()
    # Initialize the pool with the settings as a global variable
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(settings,)) as pool:
        pool.apply(func=print_path) # blocks until complete
```